# global variable not modified in imported file

Tags: python

I made a program split into 2 files like so:

```
# fileA.py
from fileB import *
add_a_bit_on_the_end()
print("Hello from file A.\nstringvar = [" + stringvar + "]")
```

and

```
# fileB.py
stringvar = "this var was initialised in file B"

def add_a_bit_on_the_end():
    global stringvar
    print("stringvar was ["+stringvar+"]")
    stringvar += " added extra bit"
    print("but now it has become ["+stringvar+"]")
```

When I run fileA.py I get...

```
stringvar was [this var was initialised in file B]
but now it has become [this var was initialised in file B added extra bit]
Hello from file A.
stringvar = [this var was initialised in file B]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is the "extra bit" lost?

Comment: The variable is global for the module it's in. Try `import fileB`, then `fileB.add_a_bit_on_the_end()`, then `print("Hello from file A.\nstringvar = [" + fileB.stringvar + "]")`

Comment: @Matthias It is a bit more complicated than that. All variables in Python are references to objects and since strings (among other data types) are immutable the call to `add_a_bit_on_the_end()` will force the creation of a new string and have `fileB.stringvar` point at that new object, while the already imported reference named only `stringvar` will still point at the original string. If this instead was an update of a mutable type e.g. a `listvar` being appended, the references would still point to the same object and the update would be visibile both through `listvar` and `fileB.listvar`.

Comment: @Mattias: Your suggestion does work - but I don't really understand why - also surely there must be a way do declare the variable as globally shared.

Comment: @Mick Everything is globally shared, as long as you are not using multiprocessing. However, there are different namespaces, which is why you need to access the (object referenced by the) variable as `fileB.stirngvar` to get the correct instance. The star import `import * from fileB` will only copy the current references. If the `fileB` internal references are updated later, as with the call to `add_a_bit_on_the_end`, the update will not affect your already copied reference.